# Can the visual options available to player plugin be set using the javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, deezer

A Deezer player widget of the kind which can be created over at http://developers.deezer.com/musicplugins/player has a couple of visual style / layout options, such as theme (dark / light) and text highlight colour, but it cannot be controlled via Javascript. Using the Deezer JS SDK to create a player enables me to control it, but there don't seem to be any of the visual options (except for format, but that doesn't do in my case). Are these options just missing from the SDK docs or are they completely unavailable when creating a player using the SDK? If the latter is the case, is there any way I could control an embed created at the Deezer Music Plugins page? By control I mean I need to be able to play / pause the player, receive play / paused events and get the currently playing track title.

Background: I'm trying to achieve a symbiosis of multiple audio and / or video playback services within a single page; the goal is to stop any currently active player when a user starts playback in another player and to have an always visible play/pause button at the top of the viewport along with the currently playing track's name. If there is any other way to do this that I'm missing, I'm all ears :-) I know I could theoretically build my own player UI, but I wanted to retain the user experience that comes with a given service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only visual options available are those which are mentioned here: http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/player

Adding the new visual options provided by the new version of the widget is in our backlog, it will be available soon.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Is there anywhere I could subscribe to receive notes about further development regarding the SDK?

Comment: Unfortunately, not for now, but we plan to implement that.